# MDX regex parsing error

Tags: c#, regex

I probably deserve to be burned at the stake for asking this, but I can't for the life of me figure out why this exception is getting thrown when I try to debug this snippet in Visual Studio. I've tested the CLR VB implementation for this regex and it returns the expected table result:

```
MDX String                                              Index  Length
[Measures].[Product-To-Order %]                         8      31
[Measures].[Gross Revenue (Stable)]                     40     35
[Measures].[Product Count]                              76     26
[Measures].[Total Order Count]                          103    30
[Measures].[Average SKU Discount]                       134    33
[Measures].[Average SKU Price Per Purchased Item]       168    49
[Component SKU].[Component SKU by Master Class].[All]   333    53
[Component SKU].[Component SKU by Master Class].[All]   690    53
[XL_Filter_Set_0]                                       749    17
[XL_Filter_Set_0]                                       806    17
[XL_Filter_HelperSet_0]                                 835    23
[XL_Filter_HelperSet_0]                                 887    23
...
```

Visual Studio seems to indicate an unhandled exception. The C# implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Data.Sql;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections;

public static class RegExFunctions {

    // RegEx matches
    [SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None, IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true, Name = "RegExMatches",
        SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.None, FillRowMethodName = "RegExMatchesRow")]
    public static IEnumerable RegExMatches(SqlString input, SqlString pattern, SqlInt32 options)
    {
        try
        {
            if (input.IsNull || pattern.IsNull) return null;
            Console.WriteLine(input);
            Console.WriteLine(pattern);
            IEnumerable matches = Regex.Matches(input.Value, pattern.Value, (RegexOptions)options.Value);
            Console.WriteLine(matches);
            //return matches;
            return Regex.Matches(input.Value, pattern.Value, (RegexOptions)options.Value);
        }
        catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException)
        {
            // Do nothing. Assume that a timeout represents no match.
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static int Main()
    {
        IEnumerable result =
            RegExMatches(
                @"\[[^\]]*\](\.(&)?\[[^\]]*\])*",
                @"SELECT {[Measures].[Product-To-Order %],[Measures].[Gross Revenue (Stable)],[Measures].[Product Count],[Measures].[Total Order Count],[Measures].[Average SKU Discount],[Measures].[Average SKU Price Per Purchased Item]} DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS , NON EMPTY Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Component SKU].[Component SKU by Master Class].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME,[Component SKU].[Component SKU by Master Class].[Master Component Class].[Class Category],[Component SKU].[Component SKU by Master Class].[Master Component Class].[ClID] ON ROWS  FROM (SELECT Generate(Hierarchize({[Component SKU].[Component SKU by Master Class].[All]}) AS [XL_Filter_Set_0], TopCount(Filter(Except(DrilldownLevel([XL_Filter_Set_0].Current AS [XL_Filter_HelperSet_0], , 0,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS), [XL_Filter_HelperSet_0]), Not IsEmpty([Measures].[Product-To-Order %])), 30, [Measures].[Product-To-Order %])) ON COLUMNS  FROM [CLV] WHERE ([Shopping Lane].[Shopping Lane].[Shopping Lane Group].&[1],[Subentity].[Subentity Filter].[Subentity].&[2],[Event].[Category].&[-488],[Event].[Is Event].&[1],[Event].[Event Start Date].[All],[Event].[Start Date by Week].[Week].&[20160703])) WHERE ([Shopping Lane].[Shopping Lane].[Shopping Lane Group].&[1],[Subentity].[Subentity Filter].[Subentity].&[2],[Event].[Category].&[-488],[Event].[Is Event].&[1],[Event].[Event Start Date].[All],[Event].[Start Date by Week].[Week].&[20160703]) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS",
                1
            );

        Console.WriteLine(result);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Pattern is fine, what kind of exception in C# does it throw.

Comment: ArgumentException. It's saying the [x-y] range is in reverse order, but I'm not sure how to actually fix this without breaking the regex.

Comment: You've go the arguments reversed.  Treating what's supposed to be the input as the regex, it sees `[Product-To-Order %]` as a character class including the ranges `t-T` and `o-O`, which are invalid.

Comment: Ha- I kept debugging the function but I didn't check the actual argument order. Guessing if I weren't so new to .net I would've read between the lines for the exception better there. Big thank you, though!

Answer (score 0):

Rookie mistake with the argument order. The call should actually look like this:

```
public static int Main()
{
        IEnumerable result =
            RegExMatches(
                @"SELECT {[Measures].[Product-To-Order %],[Measures].[Gross Revenue (Stable)],[Measures].[Product Count],[Measures].[Total Order Count],[Measures].[Average SKU Discount],[Measures].[Average SKU Price Per Purchased Item]} DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS , NON EMPTY Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Component SKU].[Component SKU by Master Class].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME,[Component SKU].[Component SKU by Master Class].[Master Component Class].[Class Category],[Component SKU].[Component SKU by Master Class].[Master Component Class].[ClID] ON ROWS  FROM (SELECT Generate(Hierarchize({[Component SKU].[Component SKU by Master Class].[All]}) AS [XL_Filter_Set_0], TopCount(Filter(Except(DrilldownLevel([XL_Filter_Set_0].Current AS [XL_Filter_HelperSet_0], , 0,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS), [XL_Filter_HelperSet_0]), Not IsEmpty([Measures].[Product-To-Order %])), 30, [Measures].[Product-To-Order %])) ON COLUMNS  FROM [CLV] WHERE ([Shopping Lane].[Shopping Lane].[Shopping Lane Group].&[1],[Subentity].[Subentity Filter].[Subentity].&[2],[Event].[Category].&[-488],[Event].[Is Event].&[1],[Event].[Event Start Date].[All],[Event].[Start Date by Week].[Week].&[20160703])) WHERE ([Shopping Lane].[Shopping Lane].[Shopping Lane Group].&[1],[Subentity].[Subentity Filter].[Subentity].&[2],[Event].[Category].&[-488],[Event].[Is Event].&[1],[Event].[Event Start Date].[All],[Event].[Start Date by Week].[Week].&[20160703]) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS",
                @"\[[^\]]*\](\.(&)?\[[^\]]*\])*",
                1
            );

        Console.WriteLine(result);

        return 0;
}
```

Thanks @sln and @AlanMoore for pointing this out!